# Load xib from Cocoapod in Storyboard

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods

I have a `storyboard` where I want to embed a `viewcontroller` in a `containerview`. The `ViewController` and its `xib` are in a `cocoapod` I made. Is it possible to embed a `viewcontroller` and its `xib` from a `cocoapod` in a `storyboard` `containerview`?

I know that if you delete the `viewcontroller's` view (in the `storyboard`) then the `storyboard` will try to load the `xib` with the same name as the `viewcontroller`. However, this isn't working. The app crashes when the `viewcontroller's` outlets aren't linked up. I can only assume it's because the `xib` is in my `cocoapod`.

I've checked that the names match and all the appropriate custom types are set in `IB` (like changing File's Owner from `UIViewController` to `MyCustomViewController`). I added the `xib` to "`resource_bundles`" in the `podspec` too.

Comment: Did you try to copy xib to your project and see if it works then?

Comment: Yes, I did try this. Storyboard is calling initWithCoder, not initWithNibName, which means it doesn't see the xib. It's likely expecting the xib to be in the current bundle, which it isn't. It's in the cocoapod's bundle.

Comment: I have the exact same problem right now and am looking for the exact same solution.

Comment: Hey, just FYI, I have created an issue in github under cocoapods repository. https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/5560

Comment: what worked for me was overriding initWithCoder and initWithNibName and forcing it to always load the xib from the cocoapod. I don't have the code anymore because it was so ugly that I just abandoned the idea.